# Not able to catch an exception in PHP with wrapper function in a try-catch with 2 inner functions that throw exceptions

Tags: php, exception, try-catch, moodle, moodle-api

I have a wrapper function in a class xyz.php class within `foreach` loop as below and other abc.php class. My catch block doesn't get executed when an exception is thrown from inner methods of wrapper class.

xyz.php class

```
foreach($rss as $rs){
  try{
     //Included file abc.php class
     $rs->wrapper();
   } catch (exception $e){
      //debug message that displays exception.
      throw $e;
   }
}
```

abc.php class

```
public function wrapper(){
   $this->function_throws_exception1();
   $this->function_throws_exception2();
}
```

Comment: exception is Exception - this may or may not matter depending on OS and how you load your files ( namespacing etc).  Based on what you describe it sounds like the exception class is not being found properly- you won't get an error for this.

Comment: It just wont get caught, its more of a concern with namespaces and autoloaders though.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks for the guess. I agree it might be something related to namespace looks like. Just adding \ before exception resolved it. ``` catch (\exception $e)  ```

Comment: It's probably ok not to capitalize as it's a Core class, but class names should always be used as they are presented even if they work in different cases.  On Linux they can become case sensitive if they are tied to a filename such as an Autoloader

Answer (score 0):

Both classes are under different namespaces. It is something related to namespace looks like. Just adding \ before exception resolved it. `catch (\exception $e)`